# Record Videos Directly To The Computer

Tags: video, storage, tethering, canon-60d, usb

I have a Canon 60D and all those programs that come with it installed on my Macbook Pro, so I want to know  if there is any way to record videos with it and store them directly on the computer using the USB cable. Since I only have a 8GB SDHC, but it's a class 2(I'll be getting a better one soon) and I need to record a 18 minutes video using my camera...

Comment: See http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/725/cinematography-should-we-make-this-on-topic

Comment: I apologize for not seeing this sooner, however based on the ongoing discussions our community is having at the meta topic @mattdm linked, I would have considered this question to fall mostly on-topic. I think we should finish our discussion on the matter, and if this question still sits in or largely in the "on-topic" pool, it should probably be reopened...at least until the video-se site is in beta.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently not.  You can shoot video in tethered mode, but it first records to the memory card and then transfers to the computer when the recording has finished.

From the [EOS Utility 2.9 for Macintosh Instruction Manual (EOS 60D)](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/7/0300004047/01/eu29-m-en.pdf):

> You can control your camera from EU
>   [EOS Utility] and shoot movies from
>   your computer screen.  You cannot
>   shoot movies without a memory card in
>   your camera [p. 41].
>
> ...image data will be downloaded from
>   the camera's memory card to your
>   computer image data. [p. 43].